# Selecting a copula then estimating its parameter

Tags: estimation, model-selection, aic, copula

Consider that we have two copula families, e.g., Frank and Gumbel. Then suppose that we want to select the best fitting family among them using AIC. Then after selecting the appropriate family, we will estimate its parameter.

That is,

1)- $\text{AIC} =-2\log L (\theta_i)+k,\, i=1,2$

Where $\theta$ contains the parameters of the relevant copula (Frank and Gumbel).

2)- Estimate the parameter.

My question is, in the AIC, we have to include the estimate parameter of the copula family. So, that means we have already knew the parameter estimate of the copula families.

Why would we need to estimate it again after selecting the family?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in thinking that to compute the AIC you need to have $-2\log\mathcal{L}$ evaluated at the maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters.

Clearly if you already have the $\hat{\theta}$ vector for your selected copula you don't need to recompute it.

Comment: Yes, that what I believe. However, all articles about copula and vine copula, select the family and estimate it parameter again. I believe that they mean to select the family based on the shape of the data, then estimate the parameters. But, still does not clear.

Comment: @Silver Yes, copula choice is frequently by means other than AIC; in that case the premise in your second sentence (where you assume it was by AIC) would not hold.

Comment: Thank for your comments. The idea that I would like to figure out is, how they use different selection models, e.g., AIC, based on the shape of the data? What do I miss here? Do that mean they suppose some value of parameters first based on the shape? I hope I can have an example. Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you need to ask a new question -- something along the lines of "How do people choose between copula families?" ... but try some searches first as something like it may have already been asked.